# how to go to next row after some entry in html while fetching data from mysql db

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

[image]i am beginner in php.

i am maintaining all student's project database.

project details (pro_image,pro_name,pro_guide,pro_cost....etc)

and displaying this is in table format in html

what i want is after some 4-5 project entries .

pointer should goes new row then add 4-5 entries again.

But all project showing in same single column

what should i do ?

here my code :

```
<html>

<head> <title> cool </title> </head>

<body>

<?php

    $conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

    if(!$conn)
    {
        die("Connection Failed :".mysqli_connect_error());
    }   

    $sql="SELECT * FROM `pro_det` ";

    mysql_select_db("dub");

    $retval=mysql_query($sql,$conn);


    if(!$retval)
    {
        die("could not get data".mysql_error());
    }

    ?>

        <table>

    <?php
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($retval,MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {

        ?> 


        <tr>    

        <img src= <?php"echo $row['pimages'] height="200" width="100"" ?> 

        <?php

        echo" </br>";

        echo" pname : {$row['pname']}</br>";

        echo" project member : {$row['pmember']}</br>";

        echo" project guide : {$row['pguide']}</br>";

        echo" project abs : {$row['pabs']}</br>";

        echo".................</br>";

        ?>

        </tr>
        <?php

    }

    echo"Fetched data sucessfully \n";

    mysql_close($conn);

?>

    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please put screen shot of your table out?

Comment: surround <td></td> with <tr></tr>

Comment: you miss <tr> fix it

Comment: You seem uncertain of your table and column names (pro_name/pname, etc..). And STOP using this deprecated API

Comment: if i use <tr> then all entry will goes in new row that i don't want 
i want matrx like represenatation

Comment: @NikhilPatil see my answer

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `tr` tag 
in Html table structure is like

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**So your modified code will look like**

```
<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($retval,MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
?> 
    <tr> 

    <img src= <?php"echo $row['pimages'] height="200" width="100"" ?> 

    <?php


    echo" <td>pname : {$row['pname']}</td>";

    echo" <td>project member : {$row['pmember']}</td>";

    echo" <td>project guide : {$row['pguide']}</td>";

    echo" <td>project abs : {$row['pabs']}</td>";


    ?>

    </tr>

    <?php
}

echo"Fetched data sucessfully \n";

mysql_close($conn);

?>

</table>
```

**EDIT 1:**
so your table structure will be like

```
 pname | project member |  project guide |  project abs  | 
  P1   | Pmem1          |         PG01   |      PA01     |
  P2   | Pmem2          |         PG02   |      PA02     |
  P3   | Pmem3          |         PG03   |      PA03     |
  P4   | Pmem4          |         PG04   |      PA04     |
```

Comment: if i use <tr> then all entry will goes in new row that i don't want i want matrx like represenatation

Comment: that is why i used <td> also for seperate coloumns

Comment: please see the picture

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot `tr` in your table

```
<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($retval,MYSQL_ASSOC))
{

    ?> 

    <tr>
    <td>    

    <img src= <?php"echo $row['pimages'] height="200" width="100"" ?> 

    <?php

    echo" </br>";

    echo" pname : {$row['pname']}</br>";

    echo" project member : {$row['pmember']}</br>";

    echo" project guide : {$row['pguide']}</br>";

    echo" project abs : {$row['pabs']}</br>";

    echo".................</br>";

    ?>

    </td>
    </tr>
    <?php

}

echo"Fetched data sucessfully \n";

mysql_close($conn);

?>

</table>
```

Comment: sir if i use <tr> then all entry will goes in new row that i don't want i want matrx like represenatation

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [modulo](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) operator on a counter in order to add a `<tr />` element every fourth line :

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <?php 
    $i = 0;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($retval,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $i++;
        /* Do your thing with tds here */
        if ($i % 4 == 0)
            echo '</tr><tr>';
    }
    ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Correct that's what i want